# building and running a branch of a go project

Tags: git, go

Blog article at this [link](http://blog.charmes.net/2014/11/how-to-properly-contribute-to-go-project.html?spref=tw) presents the following instructions for contributing to a Go lang project taking into consideration the complications that arise with import paths when you `go get` a project. I have created a `mybranch` according to the following instructions, but when I do `go build` and run the program it is running the master branch, not `mybranch`. How do I build and run a particular branch? When I do `go build` and run the program, it's running the code on `master` branch.

```
1.Fork the project
2.get the original one go get github.com/creack/termios
3.cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/creack/termios
4.Add the new remote: git remote add gcharmes git@github.com:gcharmes/termios.git
5.Fetch everything from github git fetch --all
6.Checkout in a new branch git checkout -b mybranch
7.7Contribute, as we are on the original checkout, all the paths are correct
8.Commit and push git commit -p && git push gcharmes mybranch
9.Go to github and create the pull request.
```

Comment: It might be that `go get` is resetting your code or pulling it. run your build/get process with `-x` to see what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article is for building a PR (pull request) from your fork, not for running `go get <yourfork>` (since that PR is pubished on a branch).

As the article mention:

> Use your fork only as remote placeholder, do not use it locally.

So you push your PR as a dedicated branch to your fork, and make your PR from there.

But a `go get <original_repo>` won't work until your PR has been accepted and merged on `master`.

Comment: I'm not using my fork locally. I did `go get` on the project, `cd` into the repo, created a branch, and changed some code. How do I build and run the code of that checked out branch (i.e. to know whether it's working)

Comment: How do I build and run the code? `go build` or `go install` (no need for go get at that point)